# How can I convert a .dds file to a .png in python?

Tags: python, image, dds-format

I am trying to create some images by manipulating image pieces stored in .dds files, and then write the finished image as a .png.  I see that there is a dds python module in Direct Python 11, which seems possibly sufficient except that it saves to .dds format.  Is there a way to save to another image format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Python Imaging Library](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html) has a `open()` method that supports `dds` files and has a read and `save()` can save an image to many formats (`png` included).

Note that, at the moment, only DXT1, DXT3, and DXT5 pixel formats are supported and only in RGBA mode.

Answer (score 3):

Since [Python Imaging Library](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html) link is not available, I will show a solution with the [wand](http://docs.wand-py.org/) library:

```
from wand import image
with image.Image(filename="white_rect_dxt3.dds") as img:
    img.compression = "no"
    img.save(filename="white_rect_dxt3.png")
```

And same from `.png` to `.dds`

```
from wand import image
with image.Image(filename='white_rect.png') as img:
    img.compression = "dxt3"
    img.save(filename='white_rect_dxt3.dds')
```

Comment: Couldn't get it to work with Pillow, but wand worked like a charm!

Comment: Here is an updated link:
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html

Comment: getting error: ImportError: MagickWand shared library not found.
Trying installing: pip install ImageMagick
But that also not working, ERROR: No matching distribution found for ImageMagick
Is it not a Python module?