# Open and write a .dds file in R32G32B32A32_UINT on Python

Tags: python, image, compression, python-imaging-library, dds-format

I have a .dds file in 128 bits (R32G32B32A32_UINT).
I need to open it and read the value of each pixel in Python.
Then, I need to write a new one.

Is there a way to do so?
I've searched for libraries, but they seem to not support only a limited type of .dds (Pillow for example)

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could share your `.dds` file so folks can try? You'll probably need to use Dropbox or Google Drive or somesuch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a .dds file to a .png in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46944897/how-can-i-convert-a-dds-file-to-a-png-in-python)